# Reverse horizontal scrolling direction in Libreoffice

Tags: debian, xfce, libreoffice

I am running Libreoffice on Debian Unstable with XFCE, and I ran into a bit of an issue: every time I use the touchpad to move around the document horizontally, it moves in the opposite direction (i.e. if I two-finger swipe to the right, the scrollbar moves to the left, and vice versa).
All of the components of Libreoffice seem to exhibit this behavior.
The vertical scrolling works correctly, and I've checked in the system settings that the scrolling direction should not be inverted for any input device.
Other applications where horizontal scrolling is used (such as `evince` and `firefox`) work correctly.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

**UPDATE**: for future readers, I have filed a [bug report](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126680) for this at the Document Foundation bug tracker.

Comment: Just to make sure: This is not an issue with XFCE, Debian or touchpads only. I have the same issue on Arch, Gnome and a regular mouse (with horizontal scrolling). Everything else works fine, since latest LO update (to libreoffice-fresh-6.3.0-1) I experience the same issue as OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126680#c15), the earliest version affected by this bug is `6.3.0.2 rc`, and a [patch](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126680#c18) for it has been added to version `6.3.1`.

As Debian Unstable recently received an updated version of Libreoffice (`6.3.1.2`), I've been able to verify that the behavior has indeed been fixed.
I've likewise checked that setting `Reverse scrolling direction` reverses *both* scrolling directions in LO, as intended.